# Chance of callback not getting registered for springkafka-template send method

Tags: java, callback, future, spring-kafka

I want to register a callback for the future object returned from  spring `kafkatemplate.send()`.

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(String topic, K key, V data)
```

I invoke below method on the future result of the above method.

```
void org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture.addCallback(ListenableFutureCallback<? super T> callback)
```

like this:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topicname, keyString, data).addCallback(
    new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            logger.error("Failure while sending message in kafka.", ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Data> result) {
            logger.info("Successfully sent message to kafka");
        }

    });
```

Suppose if `send()` completes the actual sending very fast and result is already set in future before me registering the callback. My callback registration will happen after the `future.set()` operation. So, there is a chance that my callback don't get executed. Isn't this a possibility?

I know such a possibility is very less. Still, can this happen? If so, what is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the future deals with that by immediately calling the callback after adding it, if it has already been satisfied - look at the source code for `SettableListenableCallback.addCallback()`.